# How do I align unlimited content inside ScrollView with React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to develop an app with react-native and when I try to align multiple TouchableOpacity components inside an ScrollView, depending on how I do it, it get some problems. Sometimes it doesn't scroll, sometimes scrolls only half the components, sometimes doesn't fit with the right size.

```
     <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.scrollView}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewContent}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>1</TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>2</TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>3</TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>4</TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>5</TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>6</TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>.</TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>.</TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>.</TouchableOpacity>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1, // To fit the all screen size.
  },
  scrollView: {
    flex:1, // To fit the all container(SafeAreaView).
  },
  scrollViewContent: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    alignContent: 'space-around',
  },
  button:{
    // Should I use flex here?
    height:"16%",
    width:"25%",
    paddingTop: 10,
    margin: 4
}
});
```

The idea is to fit 3 "buttons" per line unlimited times (I pretend to use map function for this).

Layout Example:

[image]

Comment: Since you are handling lists use ```FlatList``` instead of ```Scrollview```. check this - https://reactnative.dev/docs/using-a-listview

Comment: change your height from percentage to unitless value, eg 200 and the scroll will work just fine

Comment: Hey Rodolfo, I highly recommend to don't change the height of the content container in scrollView. Try to remove the `flexGrow` from the `scrollViewContent` and see what happens :)

Comment: Thanks @SDushan! I did it with FlatList!